# How to fix FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] File does not exist in Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to build an exe file using pyinstaller. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out, how to fix the following problem, which comes from Pandas library:

```
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in 
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 705, in 
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'data/test/file1.csv' does not exist: 
b'data/test/file1.csv'
```

I've tried to include this folder to `datas`, but it does not help. All source files and `data` folder are located in one folder.

```
files_to_add= [
     ( 'data', 'data' )
     ]

a = Analysis(['my_script.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\...'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=files_to_add,
```